# Best notation for universal / "fibrated" functions?

Tags: functions, notation

The textbook notation for writing down mathematical functions, at least the way I learned it, is

$$f\colon A\to B, x\mapsto f(x) \qquad \qquad (1)$$

I.e. we write down the domain and codomain and how elements of the domain are mapped into the codomain.

**EDIT:** General overhaul and clarification

Recently I have found that this notation seems a bit lacking for denoting what I would call "fibrated" or "universal" functions (let me know if there is an established name for this concept).

**Definition:** Given and index set $I$ and collections of disjoint spaces  $\mathcal U = \bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$ and $\mathcal V = \bigcup_{i\in I} V_i$, we say a function  $\Phi\colon\mathcal U \to \mathcal V$ "is **fibrated**" / **"fibrates"** / **feazes?$^{[1]}$** (over $I$), if and only if it maps elements "under the same index", i.e. $\Phi(u)\in V_i \iff u\in U_i$. Equivalently, there exists a family of functions $f_i\colon U_i \to V_i$ such that

$$\Phi\colon\mathcal U \to \mathcal V, u\mapsto f_{\mathfrak o(u)}(u)$$

where $\mathfrak{o}\colon \mathcal U\to I,\; \mathfrak{o}(u)=i\iff u\in U_i$ is the "indicator" function that returns the **origin** of $u$.

[1] the word I am looking for is the literal English translation for the German verb "fasern"

**Examples:**

- General vector space addition in $K$-vector spaces $(V_i)_{i\in I}$:

$$+\colon \bigcup_{i\in I} (V_i\times V_i) \longrightarrow  \bigcup_{i\in I} V_i, \; (u, v)\longmapsto u+_{V_{\mathfrak o(u))}} v$$

- The euclidean vector norm $\|\cdot\|_{\mathbb R^n}\colon \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R_{\ge0}, x\mapsto\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$. Then the general euclidean norm is a "fibrated" function (with $V_i=\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ for all $i$)

$$\|\cdot\|\colon \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow \mathbb R_{\ge0}, \; x\longmapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|_{\mathbb R^{\mathfrak o(x)}}}$$

- General matrix trace in $K$-vector spaces $(V_i)_{i\in I}$:

$$ \operatorname{tr}\colon \bigcup_{i\in I} (V_i \otimes V_i^*) \longrightarrow K, \; X \longmapsto \operatorname{tr}_{\mathfrak o(X)}(X)  $$

- The function that takes two (real, finite dimensional) vectors and returns their outer product

$$ \operatorname{outer}(u,v)\colon \bigcup_{m\in\mathbb N}\mathbb R^m \times \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow \bigcup_{m,n\in\mathbb N} \mathbb R^{m\times n}, \; (u,v) \longmapsto u\cdot v^T  $$

- The function that takes as input an $n\times n$ distance matrix and outputs the $n\times n$ permutation matrix corresponding to the shortest round trip between the $n$ points (TSP problem)
- A function that takes as input a ($N\times D$) matrix  and outputs a $(D\times F)$ matrix, where $N, D$ can be any size, but $F$ is fixed (the function "fibrates"  over $D$ and "contracts" over $N$)

---

**Bottom Line:** Now, we have seen that we are actually very familiar with many "universal"/"fibrated" functions. However, they are almost never expressed in the way like I did here; but rather what is usually is done is that the dependence on the input space is silently dropped, since it is often clear from context to which "fiber" we are referring to. E.g. we just write "$+$" and not "$+_{V}$" for vector space addition in the space $V$.  However, I hope I could make it clear with the latter examples that there are also more complicated cases where we may not get away with this.

My question is: What is a good notation for denoting fibrated functions, when I want to emphasize the eligible domain and co-domain, as well as the fact that the function "fibrates", but the actual formula of the mapping is less relevant (it may be just something like $\operatorname{NeuralNet}(x)$)

It seems that the notation (1) is ill-equipped to deal with these cases in a suitable fashion. It ends up looking clumsy for such a simple concept and one has to add paragraphs of prose.

> **There must be a better way!**

Comment: I don’t understand the definition of $g$. Do you mean that when given a vector $x$ of length $n$, it outputs a vector of length $n$? If so, then how does $f_1(x)$ make sense, since $f_1$ is only defined for length 1 vectors.

Comment: @Joppy I overhauled the question and I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I'd say $\Phi$ is a coproduct of the $f_i$ in a sense. If $\mathcal{C}$ is a category with small coproducts, there is a functor $\coprod\colon\mathcal{C}^I\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$, sending objects $(C_i)_{i\in I}$ to $\coprod_{i\in I}C_i$ and maps $(f_i\colon C_i\rightarrow D_i)_{i\in I}$ to the map $\coprod_{i\in I}f_i\colon\coprod_{i\in I}C_i\rightarrow\coprod_{i\in I}D_i$ that's the factorization of the maps $(\iota_i\circ f_i)_{i\in I}$ (where $\iota_i$ is the canonical morphism $D_i\rightarrow\coprod_{i\in I}D_i$). This abstracts your notion of fibrated map. No notational advice, though.

Comment: I’m a little rusty on my category theory, but I think that in categories with coproducts (sets and disjoint union, vector spaces and direct sum), morphisms can be decomposed into “block matrices”. (There might need to be more structure to make this work properly). You’re basically describing morphisms which are “block-diagonal”. It is also reminiscent of “graded” maps in vector spaces.